# How to parse this very hard array?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, multidimensional-array

I would like to get the current trending topics from twitter, so i'm retrieving the list using their api and get a multidimensional array back.

Does anyone has an idea how to parse this? I want to get the names back in a variable. Thanks in advance!

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [trends] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Mikhail Kalashnikov
                            [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Mikhail+Kalashnikov%22
                            [promoted_content] => 
                            [query] => %22Mikhail+Kalashnikov%22
                            [events] => 
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => #YolsuzlukLobisi
                            [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%23YolsuzlukLobisi
                            [promoted_content] => 
                            [query] => %23YolsuzlukLobisi
                            [events] => 
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => #DEMIin2013
                            [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%23DEMIin2013
                            [promoted_content] => 
                            [query] => %23DEMIin2013
                            [events] => 
                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => #GÃ¼zelPaylaÅŸÄ±mlarÄ°Ã§inTakipleÅŸelim
                            [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%23G%C3%BCzelPayla%C5%9F%C4%B1mlar%C4%B0%C3%A7inTakiple%C5%9Felim
                            [promoted_content] => 
                            [query] => %23G%C3%BCzelPayla%C5%9F%C4%B1mlar%C4%B0%C3%A7inTakiple%C5%9Felim
                            [events] => 
                        )

                    [4] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => #AÅŸkaÄ°nanmaz
                            [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%23A%C5%9Fka%C4%B0nanmaz
                            [promoted_content] => 
                            [query] => %23A%C5%9Fka%C4%B0nanmaz
                            [events] => 
                        )

                    [5] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => #AAPCON
                            [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%23AAPCON
                            [promoted_content] => 
                            [query] => %23AAPCON
                            [events] => 
                        )

                    [6] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Micah Hyde
                            [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Micah+Hyde%22
                            [promoted_content] => 
                            [query] => %22Micah+Hyde%22
                            [events] => 
                        )

                    [7] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Merry Christmas
                            [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Merry+Christmas%22
                            [promoted_content] => 
                            [query] => %22Merry+Christmas%22
                            [events] => 
                        )

                    [8] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => SarÄ±Laci SevdalÄ±larÄ± Seri TakipleÅŸiyor
                            [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Sar%C4%B1Laci+Sevdal%C4%B1lar%C4%B1+Seri+Takiple%C5%9Fiyor%22
                            [promoted_content] => 
                            [query] => %22Sar%C4%B1Laci+Sevdal%C4%B1lar%C4%B1+Seri+Takiple%C5%9Fiyor%22
                            [events] => 
                        )

                    [9] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => ÐœÐ¸Ñ…Ð°Ð¸Ð» ÐšÐ°Ð»Ð°ÑˆÐ½Ð¸ÐºÐ¾Ð²
                            [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%22%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BB+%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%22
                            [promoted_content] => 
                            [query] => %22%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BB+%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%22
                            [events] => 
                        )

                )

            [as_of] => 2013-12-23T22:48:53Z
            [created_at] => 2013-12-23T22:33:04Z
            [locations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Worldwide
                            [woeid] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Do you actually receive it like this? If yes: You need to tell them to send you something that IS ACTUALLY PARSABLE. Seriously, whoever thought that it's acceptable to send `print_r` output as an API response is an idiot. They should use JSON instead.

Comment: Maybe this one can help you out to get the name:
http://php.net/array_key_exists

Comment: That's not "parsing", that's traversing. Paste your json to http://array.include-once.org/ to see.

Comment: Ok i got my json now with json_encode().. but now... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the object you outputted is stored in `$data`:

```
foreach ($data[0]->trends as $trend)
{
   // Do something with $trend->name
}
```